# Hoffman Kunze, reasonable name for the scalar c with $\det A = c$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am working on problem 5.3.11 of Kunze.

$$$$

> Let $T$ be a linear operator on $F^n$. Define
>
> $D_T(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, ..., \alpha_n) = \det(T\alpha_1, T\alpha_2,
>  ..., T\alpha_n) $
>
> (a) Show that $D_T$ is an alternating $n$-linear function.
>
> (b) If
>
> $c = \det(T\epsilon_1, T\epsilon_2, ..., T\epsilon_n)$
>
> show that for any $n$ vectors $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, ..., \alpha_n$ we
> have
>
> $\det(T\alpha_1, T\alpha_2, ..., T\alpha_n) = c\det(\alpha_1, \alpha_2,
>  ..., \alpha_n)$
>
> (c) if $B$ is any ordered basis for $F^n$ and $A$ is the matrix of $T$
> in the ordered basis $B$, show that $\det A=c$
>
> (d) What do you think is a reasonable name for the scalar $c$?

Here, I've done up to (c) and showed the important part but I can't think of a suitable name for scalar $c$. And I couldn't find hints regarding this either. Can you help me figure out? If this $c$ indeed has a famous name, a mere name would help a lot, since I have no idea what to search for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overthinking it. I believe he simply meant that it's appropriate to define the determinant of a *linear operator* $T$ by $\det T\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}c$.